# Turbulence: Suggest research papers similar to this experiment

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I am trying to find the effect on turbulence characteristics when flow passes through a converging section. For this experiment I will use a PIV system to gather data about the flow. 
However, I could not find any specific literature on flow through symmetric converging channel. (The converging channel I would be using is type of a converging hopper with a circular hole exit.) I have attached a 2d drawing of this [image]

Please advise if you know any similar papers relating to this.

Comment: I believe that such a situation is covered by Rapid Distortion Theory. It shouldn't be hard to find some papers about it.

Comment: http://heattransfer.asmedigitalcollection.asme.org/article.aspx?articleid=1434180